# New object with unique field - Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2012

For example I have that class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public class Example{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(name = "example_name", unique=true)
String name;

public Example(){}
//getters and setters
}

//Hibernate logic
Example ex = new Example();
ex.setName("something");
```

If I want again save object with name "something" I get error. How to chceck that value before save session?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same session - before saving the Example do a call `findByName` (implementing a logic to check whether an Example exists with that name) for that domain object if it does not exist then save else throw an exception that the name is already used.